# Download the source code for a specific project at cs.android.com

Tags: android

I want to download the following source code:

https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/integration-tests/material-catalog/

To do this, I had to install repo and run the init command. I then read that you use the sync command to download projects. But all I could gather from the documenation is that the sync command downloads the entire source code for Android.

How do I use the repo command to download just the project I want?

Comment: Download it where?

Comment: Locally to my own computer.

Comment: Does your code available here? https://github.com/android/compose-samples

Comment: No. That's not the same thing. I want to download code from cs.android.com

Comment: Ok, even though it download entire project, what is the issue navigating to the particular material project and make it a new copy?

Comment: I don't think you understand. Using the repo command downloads the entire Android source code and not the project I am referring to. There is no way to to perform a git clone of the project. BTW, each of the projects listed at https://github.com/android/compose-samples have links to their Github source files. But the one on the Material Catalog is NOT a Github project. You can't download that project.

Comment: Why don't you try this? repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b compose/material/material/integration-tests/material-catalog/ --partial-clone --clone-filter=blob:limit=10M

Comment: I believe you see the difference in the init command I gave, there is an option to provide path to what you want to download actually, so it should work.

Comment: You will get an "invalid refspec" with the command you indicated.

Comment: Ok, I don't have repo in my machine to try out, just provided hint from here https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main: